# fullCalendar dayClick go to the day that is clicked

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

is there a way to go to the agandaDay of the clicked day. The code below is what I have so far but it's not working.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
                    .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
  }
```

What this does it goes to either the current date (today) or to the last manually accessed date. What else do I need to do to make go to the agendaDay of the clicked day/date?

Answer (score 3):

FullCalendar (I think from 2.0) uses momentjs library to deal with dates

date must be calculated previously, before passing to fullcalendar:

```
var date = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01');
```

Detailed instructions:

Goto http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/demos/basic-views.html

Open console and put these lines, line by line (I think this is the issue):

```
var date = $.fullCalendar.moment('2014-05-01');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
```

You got this result (image)

[image]

The reason that cascade:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay').fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
```

does not work is that returning valur from changeView is not return any object

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Late to the answer, but just ran into this myself and thought this fiddle would be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/88n10j7f/

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  $('.calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay')
  $('.calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Very helpful. Thanks!